# How use nodejs treads

Tags: node.js

I want to use multiple threads and receive intermediate calculations of child thread in the parent thread without blocking it. How i can implament this?

Comment: Node is single threaded, so the quick answer is "you can't". But you can try something like [threads-a-go-go](https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo) if you *have* to use threads. You can also try out the [cluster module](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html).

Comment: Use `require('child_process').fork`  http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options